# Can I self-isolate in a different country from the UK and then travel to the UK without being in solitary confinement again?

Tags: uk, international-travel, spain, covid-19, spanish-citizens

I am a Spanish citizen and I would like to travel to the UK from Spain, Edinburgh more specifically. But currently, I would need to self-isolate for 14 days since the country is not on the [list of exemptions since the 26 July](https://www.gov.scot/publications/coronavirus-covid-19-public-health-checks-at-borders/pages/exemptions/).

> Spain (this does not apply to arrivals from 00:01 on 26 July 2020)

I have friends in other countries which are exempt to make the confinement, Poland for instance. Then I could spend all those days in their home and avoid expensive accommodation in Edinburgh, I think it is not worthwhile paying so much just to stay in a flat all the time. So, my question is:

Can go there to spend the 14 days in self-isolation and then justify in some way that I have been there doing my confinement. Is this possible?

Actually I don’t know where I could ask this question, is there any contact number or email from the UK government where I can reassure this?

I also found that [some people could not travel from the UK to Spain by plane](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/159250/will-i-have-issues-entering-the-uk-from-spain-as-a-canadian-due-to-covid)? Can that happen to me if the rules change these days?

Comment: The Home Office makes itself unreachable to the public about these matters

Comment: I have to ask- how do you intend to travel from Poland to the UK while isolating? I'm assuming a private plane and a giant hamster ball are involved?

Comment: @Studoku nope, I might not explain correctly. First, I would take a flight to Poland or any other country from where the UK accept people directly without self-confinement. Then, 14 days later I would take the flight to the UK. Poland was just an example, I think currently they do not accept passengers from Spain as far as I know (just tourists I mean). Anyway I would take some risks, as jcaron says, the UK could remove some country from the list of exempts. [This map says that flights Spain-Poland are suspended](https://www.officeholidays.com/coronavirus/poland)

Comment: I think you know the answer.  Just follow the rules and don't try to invent exceptions that do not exist.  Everyone is in the same boat, just follow the rules.  If you don't like it, don't travel.

Comment: I am just asking to save some money in accommodation @LittleCode

Comment: @LittleCode I'm not sure that's fair. If OP travels to a country with a lower risk first and stays there long enough to tell if they got sick from their ordinal country, then they aren't posing any higher of a risk than someone who is originally from the lower risk country. And a lot of the rules are about what country you spent the last two weeks in, not your resident country, so it's not unreasonable to ask if this is within the rules.

Comment: @LittleCode and after reading the answer, I see what OP is asking to do *is* within the rules, both in spirit and by the letter. So your comment telling them to follow the rules is pointless.

Comment: @Kat the rules of the UK, sure, but what are the rules of Poland here?  If they self isolate in their friends house, what does that mean for their friend?  Can they isolate from them in their house for 14 days, or will their friend have to join them in isolation?

Comment: @Kat Don't try to invent excuses.  The rules are clear. If the country is on the list, you quarantine on arrival in the UK. Simple. You land in the UK and you are subject to the rules of the UK government. Stop inventing excuses.  As I said, if you don't like it, don't travel. We are all in the same boat, show some respect for others around you who are making an effort to stop the spread of the virus.

Comment: @ChesuCR, saving money in accomodation is not an excuse for ignoring the clear rules set out by the UK government.  If a foreign country is on the list, you quarantine.  Simple. There is no "interpretation" of the rules.

Comment: @LittleCode, is there really any need to take such a rude tone? You've misunderstood the question which can be simplified to *if I travel from Spain to a country where the UK doesn't require quarantine on arrival from, then stay there for 14 days, will I be quarantine free if I then travel to the UK?*, which has been answered below.

Comment: @LittleCode yes, the rules are clear: traveling from a country you've spent at least the last two weeks in and which is on the exemption list means you don't have to quarantine upon arrival.  No rules are being ignored, and OP asked this to make sure their plan is within the rules. You may not like that the rules allow this but they certainly do.

Comment: @Moo I don't know the rules in Poland, but I imagine if OP is allowed to travel there that a two week isolation upon arrival will probably fulfill any requirements. It sounds like they're not set on Poland specifically so obviously they'll have to look into the rules of whatever country they decide, but it's out of scope for this question. There's no indication that OP plans to ignore the rules of the intermediary country.

Comment: @Rob I'm not being rude.  The OP clearly stated they want to "save money on accomodation" by skipping the quarantine rules.  As far as I'm concerned that's looking to avoid the clear rules.  I've got zero tolerance for people looking to avoid clear rules by making up exceptions that do not exist.  We are all in the same boat.  Don't like 14 day quarantine, don't travel to that country. Simple !

Comment: @LittleCode, re-read the question. You are the only person who has (mis-)interpreted the posters question that way. What they propose is perfectly fair and reasonable, assuming there's a 3rd country to spend 14 days in which then doesn't require them to quarantine upon arrival in the UK.

Comment: @LittleCode I don't want to break the rules. Rob is right.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your citizenship is irrelevant, the only question is where you have been recently. So if you are arriving from a country which is exempt from quarantine requirements, and have been there long enough (I think this is 14 days, that needs to be checked), you don't need to quarantine when you arrive in the UK.

If that other country does not require you to quarantine when arriving from Spain, then you don't **need** to quarantine at all, though you most certainly should.

Note however that countries which are exempt from the quarantine requirement today may not be exempt in 2 weeks, as has been seen repeatedly for many other countries.

Comment: It is in fact 14 days — see paragraph 6(1)(b) in the regulation [here](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ssi/2020/169/regulation/6).

Comment: "`though you most certainly should`" +1